# Which Data structure is suitable queue or stack?

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack

I am given a task to develop an application that will manage the appointment of patients coming for treatment. There can be two types of patients called normal patients and emergency patients. The system will take information of every patient and decide the turn of patient on the basis of type of patient.

If the patient will be from normal category, it will take appointment on the basis of arrival while the emergency patient will take appointment early than normal patients. All normal and emergency patients will be added into same system but appointment will be given differently. Every emergency patient will get appointment immediately.

Which data structure from Stack and Queue will be most efficient choice for the development of required application.

Note: You are not allowed to use any other data structures like priority queue and double ended queue

According to me, queue is a better option for calling normal patients because this follows FIFO. But how to deal with emergency patients without using priority queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you prohibited from using two queues ? If not use two one for emergency patients the other for regular patients.

Comment: There's no such prohibition but how can I create a queue for emergency patients

Comment: basicly create a structure or class (depends on which language you are using) after that create two instance name one of it regularPatient name second one emergencyPatient after that when you are adding a patient to queue you should check status of the patient and if patient is emergency patient add it to emergency queue if its not add it to regular queue when you do someting about the patient first you need to check emergency queue if its not empty get patient from emergecy queue if its empty get patient from regular queue

Answer (score 0):

> Which data structure from Stack and Queue will be most efficient choice for the development of required application.

A stack won't be of much help since that's a LIFO ("last in, first out") container. You should use a queue.

For the simple case, you could use two separate regular FIFO ("first in, first out") queues. When it's time to pick a patient:

- If the emergency queue is not empty, pick one from that queue.
- otherwise pick from the other queue.

A more generic solution is to use a **priority queue**.

Upon initial inspection of a new patient, you assign a priority to the patient, which can be a number from 0-100 for example. The patient is then placed in the priority queue, which automatically puts the patient before all other patiens with a lower priority.

When it's time to pick a patient you will always pick the first in line since the patients are lined up in the queue based on the priority of the matter.

A second sorting parameter for the priority queue could be the time of arrival, so that two patients that have been assigned the same priority are ordered according to when they came to seek help.